# jquery php problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hi Can anybody tell me what I'm doin wrong here..?
I want to post values from the form to the 'some.php' file to insert in the db.
The problem is that sometimes the values go in.. sometimes it dosn't.. tried various other options but it doesn't seem to work..
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Here's the HTML code

```
<form method="POST" id="Form1" name="Form1">        
     <td>Number :<input name='numbr' type="text" maxlength="10" size="15"></td>
     <td>Amount <input name='amt' type="text" maxlength="4" size="4"></td>
     <td><input id="done" type="submit" value="Done"> | </td>
</form>
```

Here's the js file

```
var dataString = $('#Form1').serialize();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(){`enter code here`
        alert('Boom!')
    }
});
```

Ps: it does not alert('Boom') as well.. and im retrieving data in the php file like this..

```
$num = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['numbr']);
$amt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['amt']);
```

Comment: You should post the PHP code too.

Comment: If 'enter code here' is really in your code then that might be the problem.

Comment: are you getting any javascript errors ?

Answer (score 2):

Do an alert on `dataString` to see what it is serialized to. On your serverside, output the same to ensure it is received. On your browser, install tools such as `httpwatch` or `firebug` to watch the http traffic.

Finally, "`enter code here`", is that an example or is it really what is going into your javascript codes?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that should work for you.

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/2wF6M/ (note here `success` won't work as `some.php` is not there, but it sends request)

```
$(function(){
  var dataString = $('#Form1').serialize();
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
            alert('Boom!') 
        } 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

serialize may be having problems due to malformed html try using this html

```
<form method="POST" id="Form1" name="Form1">       
    <ul> 
         <li><label>Number :</label><input name='numbr' type="text" maxlength="10" size="15" /></li>
         <li><label>Amount</label> <input name='amt' type="text" maxlength="4" size="4" /></li>
         <li><input id="done" type="submit" value="Done" /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

we also need to see your php